# Weekly Sum Dynamic Pivot MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a hard time working with Dynamic Pivots in MySQL, been struggling with the project for over 5 weeks now.
With this code I am able to generate the Dynamic Pivot:

```
if($period == "YEARWEEK"){
    $sql = "
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'SUM(CASE WHEN (".$period."(redeem_pledge)) = ',
          (".$period."(redeem_pledge)),
          ' THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `',
          (".$period."(redeem_pledge)),
          '`'
        )
      ORDER BY redeem_pledge ASC ) AS `pivot_columns`
    FROM record_pledge
    WHERE redeem_pledge BETWEEN ? AND ?
    ORDER BY redeem_pledge ASC
";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$date_from = $this->input->get('date_from') ? $this->input->get('date_from') : '2017-05-01';
$date_to   = $this->input->get('date_to') ? $this->input->get('date_to') : date('Y-m-d');
$stmt->execute([$date_from, $date_to]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->closeCursor();
$pivot_columns = $row['pivot_columns'];

$sql = "
    SELECT title AS `Pledge Purpose`, {$pivot_columns}
    from record_pledge t1
    join setting_pledge_purpose ON t1.purpose_pledge = 
    setting_pledge_purpose.id
    WHERE t1.`redeem_pledge` BETWEEN ? AND ?
    GROUP BY title asc WITH ROLLUP
    ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$date_from, $date_to]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

I have no issue generating monthly or yearly reports using this method by switching the value of $period by passing a parameter passed to it. But when I use YEARWEEK as the function the data is duplicated as shown below:

[image]

Parameters passed to it:

```
date_from=2017-06-01
date_to=2017-10-01
period=YEARWEEK
```

SQL FIDDLE:
[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55e856)
This is the last piece of the puzzle and would appreciate any help!!!!!

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: A piece of the puzzle, certainly, but not the last!

Comment: I ran your first query, copied that output into second query replacing `{pivot_columns}` and no data repeats. See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55e856/5/0). Hence, I cannot reproduce your issue. Always make sure MCVE reproduces problem.

Comment: I've tagged this using PHP and MySQL, replicating it in PHP might be more helpful to debug if it's a query issue or php issue.

Comment: Likely it is a PHP issue. However, your code cuts off how it is displayed on screen. Show the second query fetch.

Comment: If you see the image I did a var_dump above the table, the data duplicates directly from searching.

Comment: I see no `var_dump` in your code. We need to see how this array is built.

Comment: the var_dump is above the table in the image, I have also added the way the array is built. Please check.

Comment: Can you confirm the data in your fiddle renders the same `var_dump(results)` as in image?

Comment: Yes I can confirm it