# Dynamic Pivot MYSQL incomplete SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have been having trouble with a project i've been working on for about 5 weeks now, i've made various stackoverflow posts along the way and i'm almost at the final hurdle.

I was having issues with duplicated data searching weekly sums but I seem to have figured that out but now my statement isn't completing. 
REf:
[Weekly Sum Dynamic Pivot MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758117/weekly-sum-dynamic-pivot-mysql)

Here is a fiddle with the data.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3610

```
$period = 'YEARWEEK';


    $sql = "
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'SUM(CASE WHEN (".$period."(date)) = ',
          (".$period."(date)),
          ' THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `',
          (".$period."(date)),
          '`'
        )
      ORDER BY date ASC ) AS `pivot_columns`
    FROM record_offering
    WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
    ORDER BY date ASC
";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$date_from = '2017-01-01';
$date_to   = '2017-10-01';
$stmt->execute([$date_from, $date_to]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->closeCursor();
$pivot_columns = $row['pivot_columns'];

$sql = "
    SELECT title AS `Service`, {$pivot_columns}
    from record_offering t1
    join setting_service ON t1.service_id = setting_service.id
    WHERE t1.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
    GROUP BY title asc WITH ROLLUP
";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$date_from, $date_to]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

As you can see the last statement is incomplete:

```
SELECT title AS `Service`, SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201635 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201635`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201703 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201703`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201709 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201709`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201713 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201713`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201715 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201715`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201717 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201717`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201718 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201718`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201722 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201722`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201723 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201723`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201725 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201725`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201726 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201726`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201735 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201735`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201736 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201736`,
SUM(CASE WHEN (YEARWEEK(date)) = 201
from record_offering t1
join setting_service ON t1.service_id = setting_service.id
WHERE t1.`date` BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY title asc WITH ROLLUP
```

I have tried escaping the query in various ways but either the query completes and my data is duplicated or it doesn't compile at all.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code. It would massively simplify this query. From my perspective, your present strategy is completely back to front

Comment: My inital try was just a basic sum and group query which I then transformed using php but it would not aggregate the data past daily correctly. I was then adviced to try pivot

Comment: I just cannot see the point of pivoting data this way when presentation layer code is available.

Comment: I have a long way to go, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT has a limit off 1024 bytes.

Use

`SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet`

Before the GROUP_CONCAT query.

Comment: Had no idea about that, currently this project is being run on shared hosting, I believe I will need root access for this correct?

Comment: @Enoch S No You can use this setting without SUPER privilege or without root access

Answer (score 0):

To my way of thinking, this (or something very like it) is ALL the sql you need for this problem. *Everything* else can, and should, be handled in the presentation layer.

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(x.date) yw
     , x.title
     , COALESCE(SUM(y.amount),0) total
  FROM setting_service x
  LEFT
  JOIN record_offering y
    ON y.service_id = x.id
 GROUP 
    BY yw
     , x.id;
```

Comment: my initial effort is as you have said. this is the question I posted on SA for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267138/datatables-dates-at-the-top-and-data-cells-going-from-left-to-right

Comment: I think that looks like a much better approach. The only issue is the 'ROLLUP' - which you can do just as easily with a bit of javascript.

Comment: that could have been done but the issue was that it was not aggregating the data correctly. http://www.phpwin.org/s/0xFWpF is the fiddle. if you change the thead and tbody interval to +1 day, the data is correct but on +1 week it doesnt aggregate as the first should have been 5